React Native - My app as a white gap at the bottom and top
My screen has a white gap at the bottom and top. Iphone 13
I am using expo and react-navigation.
I have tried SafeAreaView, SafeAreaProvider and etc. Any Ideas of what could be happening?
At this moment my login screen looks like the image on the left I would like it to look like the image on the right.

index.tsx
    import * as React from 'react';
    import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
    import LoginOrRegister from './screens/LoginOrRegister';
    import Login from './screens/Login';
    import 'react-native-screens';
    import { SafeAreaProvider} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
    
    
    function index() {
      const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
     
      return (
       <SafeAreaProvider style={{flex:1}}>
        <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="LoginOrRegister">
                
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="LoginOrRegister" component={LoginOrRegister} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
          </Stack.Navigator>
              
        </NavigationContainer>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
      
    
      );
    }
    export default index;

Login.tsx
    import {
        useSafeAreaInsets,
      } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
    
    import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
      
      function Login() {
        const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
      
        return (
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
              alignItems: 'center',
              backgroundColor: 'green',
      
              // Paddings to handle safe area
              paddingTop: insets.top,
              paddingBottom: insets.bottom,
              paddingLeft: insets.left,
              paddingRight: insets.right,
            }}
          >
            <Text>This is top text.</Text>
            <Text>This is bottom text.</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    
      export default Login;


SafeAreaView makes sure your screen isn't being captured by any mobile device sensor bars etc. What you want to have is to remove that SafeAreaView.
function index() {
      const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
     
      return (
        <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="LoginOrRegister">
                
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="LoginOrRegister" component={LoginOrRegister} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
          </Stack.Navigator>
              
        </NavigationContainer>£
      
    
      );
    }

And remove dynamic inset paddings in screens:
function Login() {
        return (
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
              alignItems: 'center',
              backgroundColor: 'green',
            }}
          >
            <Text>This is top text.</Text>
            <Text>This is bottom text.</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }

But this is not a good practice. In general you want to use SafeAreaView to make sure your content isn't being blocked by device's screen overlaying parts.

I tried it and the it is still the same. The login view does not cover the entire screen.
